Flash message not displaying after logging out
Log out route
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  delete req.session.returnTo;
  req.flash('success', 'Successfully Logged Out!');
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/home');
})


Route for rendering home view
app.get('/home',(req,res) =>{
    const isLoggedIn = req.session.user ? true : false;
    res.render('home', { isLoggedIn });
})

Home view
<% } if (!isLoggedIn)  { %>
        <% if (success.length > 0 ) {%>
          <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <%= success %>
            <alert type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></alert>
        </div>
        <% } %>
   <% } %>


Explaination of main issue
My flahes are working fine for every other route and view for example login and signup the only issue i am facing is that in my logout route after deleting the session the flash message does not appear
when i removed the code  req.session.destroy();  the flash message worked fine i a;so searched internet to find solution but didnt find something usefull. your help will be appreciated a lot.

I haven't got a chance to test your code yet but one question comes on top of my head is Can we put more than 1 request(req) in a code? I mean, do you currently have working a code where there are two (or more) request?

How did you configure express-session and connect-flash? Share the code about these two configurations.

@FanoFN yes i am using two req at the same time in my code

@Subha i have configured them in my main.js file and all session requesta are working in my other routes like post ang get

The “documentation” of connect-flash says The flash is a special area of the session used for storing messages. and Flash messages are stored in the session., so it would absolutely make sense that it doesn't work anymore after destroying the session.

As we know destroying a session will affect its dependent references, therefore the flash messages if any stored in the session object
will also be lost. Please see below for two workarounds:
Use a global property as below.
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  delete req.session.returnTo;
  req.session.destroy();
  global.location = 'logout';
  res.redirect('/home');
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  const isLoggedIn = req.session.user ? true : false;
  if (global.location == 'logout') {
    req.flash('message', 'Successfully Logged Out!');
    delete global.location;
  }
  res.render('home', { isLoggedIn });
});

Use redirect with a query string as shown below.
   app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
      delete req.session.returnTo;
      req.session.destroy();
      res.redirect(
        require('url').format({
          pathname: '/home',
          query: {
            location: 'logout',
          },
        })
      );
    });
    
    app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
      const isLoggedIn = req.session.user ? true : false;
      if (req.query.location == 'logout') {
        req.flash('message', 'Successfully Logged Out!');
      }
      res.render('home', { isLoggedIn });
    });

Citations:
How do I redirect in expressjs while passing some context?
how to send flash logout message express or check if redirected
